# Magic of scanf() function?

Tags: c, input, scanf

Why run this code and print whole string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    while(a!='q')
    {
        scanf("%c",&a);
        printf("%c",a);
    }
}
```

Enter string except q, and finally press enter key. Only now your string will print on the screen. Why?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your question.

Comment: main does not return void; main returns an int.

Comment: can you explain your comment iconik

Comment: @Govind, you use void main(). That is incorrect. Main returns an int, hence: int main()

Comment: you mean I cant use void as return of main function

Comment: Indeed. `main` is a special function because it is called automatically when your program starts. And it is called by something that expects an `int` in return. So you should also have `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Comment: iconiK wants to tell you that according to the c++ standard, it is mandatory for main to return an int (even if most compilers will accept a void main for backwards compatibility with pre-standard c++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not with scanf, it is with your printf call.

Printf buffers output until a new line is reached, so the program will not display anything until you `printf("\n");`. (Which also happens when someone presses enter, you output their return to the screen which causes the buffer to flush.)

If you don't want to break up your output with `printf("\n")`, then you can use `fflush(stdout)` to manually flush the buffer without printing anything, like this:

```
int a;
while(a!='q')
{
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%c",a);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, I had copied the typo from the original question.

Comment: might want to edit and restyle the code in the question again. Please?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, that code won't compile - print is not a function in C, printf is one one you're looking for.

As for what I think you are asking, I don't know why you would want to print every character you read until you read q; it seems kinda pointless.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to define a to be of char type:

```
char a;
```

When you hit enter, the while loop will run for so many times as many characters you have inputed.Try this to see what is happening:

```
char a = 0;
int i = 0;
while(a!='q')
{
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%d:%c",i++,a);
}
```

Comment: its also possible with int yar(Friend)